# jQuery: Close What's Open, Open What's Closed

Tags: jquery, animation, slidetoggle, slidedown, slideup

I am working on a simple accordion-like vertical menu:

http://www.cybart.com/bscg/

Clicking on OUR SOLUTIONS, PRODUCT COVERAGE, OUR TEAM or CONTACT US opens or closes the submenus.

However, if you click on two or more of those links in a row, all the submenus will open.

I want the first click on any of the menu items to open its submenu and close those that are currently open. The second click should just close the submenu of the link being clicked.

I would be grateful for the expertly advice.

Comment: As a side note, I'd recommend changing the look of the menu a little bit (maybe indenting the opened parts). After opening one, it is a little hard to tell what is a new link and what will collapse the menu.

Comment: Haha, I was just doing that while you were typing this note. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the jQuery :visible selector.  On the click event, slide up whichever one is already visible and slide down the one you want to open.

EDIT: Here's a code snippet I used in the past to do this.  Note I am using definition lists (dl, dt, dd) instead of your unordered lists (ul and li), but you can adapt the code:

```
$("dt span").click(function () {
   var dd = $(this).parent().next();
    if (dd.is(":visible")) {
        dd.slideUp("slow");
    } else {
        $("dd:visible").slideUp("slow");
        dd.slideDown("slow");
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT: Actual code as requested by the OP:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Accordion</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="access">
      <!-- Use spans so that only clicks on the item name are processed -->
      <li><span class="item">Item 1</span>
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1 - A</li>
          <li>Item 1 - B</li>
          <li>Item 1 - C</li>
        </ul>
     </li>
      <li><span class="item">Item 2</span>
        <ul>
          <li>Item 2 - A</li>
          <li>Item 2 - B</li>
          <li>Item 2 - C</li>
        </ul>
     </li>
      <li><span class="item">Item 3</span>
        <ul>
          <li>Item 3 - A</li>
          <li>Item 3 - B</li>
          <li>Item 3 - C</li>
        </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

        // All sections rolled up to start
        $("ul#access ul").hide();

        // Open or close as necessary
        $("span.item").click(function () {
            var ul = $(this).next();
            if (ul.is(":visible")) {
                ul.slideUp("slow");
            } else {
                $("ul#access ul:visible").slideUp("slow");
                ul.slideDown("slow");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Explanation: I used spans so that only the text of each item triggers the accordion behavior.  When a span is clicked on, we say $(this).next() to get to the inner ul.  If you don't use spans and you attach the click handler to the outer li, then clicks inside the submenu will trigger the closing of the outer li.

Comment: Thank you Ray. I couldn't figure out how to adapt your code, so I came up with min, using :visible selector, as you suggested. It almost works, but for some reason, when I click the link in the ul ul (submenu), it reacts in the same way as if I clicked the higher level link (ul). It closes the submenu. I want to keep it open. Could you take a look please? I'm posting my snippet in the body of my question.

Comment: I modified my answer to provide a complete HTML page that uses ul and li as in your site, with an id "#access".  I think this one should be much easier to adapt.

Comment: Thank you for sticking with me, Ray. I tried the modified code. For some reason, the HTML page doesn't work when I open it in the browser. When I tried to use your code in my site, it didn't work either. The only thing that happened, after I replaced ('ul#access>li') with ('#access ul li') - is that a click on the link slides up (hides) the link that's been clicked. Could you take a look at my code in the body of the question? Maybe you could suggest how I could select the elements of the list more correctly?

Comment: Correction: HTML page worked (something happened during copy/paste phase and I had to clean up the quotes a bit), but the code is a little too long, and it has the same problem as the shorter snippet that I posted in the body of my question: the click on the submenu link closes the submenu. I want it to stay open. Could you please take a look at my code? Maybe you could suggest how to select only the higher level ul?

Comment: Oh now I see.  Sure, Dimitri.  To ensure only the text of the submenu is handled, I am afraid you will have to use spans and attach then handler to it.  I have edited my answer.  Hope you get it!

Comment: Thank you Ray. Not possible in my particular situation: too much php editing. But someone else helped me to find an alternative answer which is also very good: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632798/jquery-selecting-only-ul-not-ul-ul