# jQuery: Selecting only ul, not ul ul

Tags: jquery, select, html-lists, slidedown, slideup

I'm trying to beat a basic accordion style menu into submission – using jQuery.

Here's the menu:

http://www.cybart.com/bscg/

Here's a snippet of code that gives it accordion functionality:

```
$('#access ul li').click(function(){
        $('#access ul ul:visible').slideUp();
        $(this).children('ul:hidden').slideDown();

    });
```

**The problem: a click on a sub-menu link makes the submenu slide up (and close).**

I want to keep the submenu open when the submenu link is clicked, and slide up only when a top level links are clicked.

How can I select only the top level ul with jQuery to animate the submenu? Or is there a way to select the sub-menu link and "tell it" to keep the submenu open on click?

I would appreciate your wisdom!

Comment: Where is the menu in question at the link you provide?

Comment: Approx. 150px below the words Consulting Group that appear in the logo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you need to use the `>` operator in CSS.

`.foo > .bar` selects all elements with class `bar` that is a direct child of an element with class `foo`

Got it, working code:

```
$('#access ul.menu > li > a').click(function(){
        $('#access ul ul:visible').slideUp();
        $(this).siblings('ul').slideDown();
    });
});
```

---

To keep the menu from sliding back up again this works:

```
$('#access ul.menu > li > a').click(function(){
        var siblingUl = $(this).siblings('ul');
        if(siblingUl.is(':visible')) { // The currently open menu was clicked
            // Remove this if you want nothing to happen
            siblingUl.slideUp();
            return;
        }

        $('#access ul ul:visible').slideUp();
        siblingUl.slideDown();
    });
});
```

Comment: That would seem to be correct, however, it doesn't work. When I add the > operator in my code, it behaves exactly in the same way as without it. A click on the submenu link closes the submenu. I would appreciate more ideas from you, Nicklas.

Comment: Thank you Nicklas. stopPropagation snippet doesn't change anything. But I have a feeling you're onto something. Could you storm this citadel a little more with me please? What could be preventing your snippet from making the difference?

Comment: Ah, the reason seems to be that you're actually clicking the li again, see the updated code.

Comment: That kills the menu. It just stops responding to any clicks. But - again - I have a feeling the solution should be somewhere close.

Comment: SOLVED. No need to use this: $('#access ul.menu >li a') at the top. Instead, use this: $('#access ul ul li a') as a selection for the stopPropagation() method. Thank you Nicklas! You solved it for me!

Comment: I would say that my final solution (now in the answer) is a better one, it won't break if you add more elements.

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1277/discussion-between-nicklas-a-and-dimitri-vorontzov)

Comment: EVEN BETTER! Thank you, Nicklas!

Comment: Nicklas, one more thing. (I wonder if you still read comments on this page.) If I click on the parent link of the open submenu, the submenu closes and then opens again. What would be a good way to modify this code to either make it just close and not open again - or do nothing? I would appreciate if you cold suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop the menu from closing because the browser is making a new request and loading the menu fresh when you click on the links.  Just watch the URL bar.  When you click the sub-menu links, the URL changes.

You'll need to add something to the URL to stop the sub-menu from collapsing, or test the URL to see if it should re-open the accordion after the page loads.

Comment: Thank you Rockerest. Totally off-mark, but thank you for trying to help.

Comment: Hmm.  I hope you investigated this.  Maybe you could explain why this is off the mark, since this is exactly what's happening.

Comment: Long story short, that's not what I asked about. But as I said, I do very much appreciate your willingness to help. I am being sincere when I say this.

Comment: Hmm, okay, I guess I'm not understanding the problem based on your description and the current actions on your site.  Hope everything works out! :)

Comment: Yes. Thank you Rockerest. I think the misunderstanding came from the fact that you joined the discussion just about when the problem was successfully fixed - you were looking at the menu that already worked the way it was supposed to. But again, I can't help feeling grateful for your eagerness to help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is much simpler and works for me.

```
$(".parent").click(function() {
   $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

i have took 10 minutes to read and understand your code because you have a lot of styles and id's and this is complicating it a lot, take care of the best practices

All you need is something like

```
<ul>
  <li>
   <a class="menu">Menu</a>
    <ul>
       <li><a>Submenu</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Other menu</li>
</ul>

...

$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".menu").click(function(){
      $(this).next().toggle()
  })

})
```

Comment: what he is telling you is that you're offering advice about HTML that *WordPress* emits, and that is not something the author of this question controls.